# faacEncOpen why maxOutput bytes is unsigned long*

Tags: c, libfaac

I'm trying to use `libfaac` and I'm curious why `faacEncOpen()` receives `maxOutputBytes` as  `unsigned long*` as it's only to say how many bytes can write to output buffer.

So why it is a pointer?

Comment: To store the number of bytes actually written?

Comment: It looks like that function tells you what maxOutputBytes is, rather than you telling it what you want.

Comment: Thanks Mat function writes to that pointer a value that says me how long output buffer should i make